# a region homeomorphic with klein bottle

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

prove that if we consider this shape in the picture below with the equivalency relation that : a & b are in one class if they are antipoles in inner or outer circles, then the induced  quotient space is homeomorphic with the klein bottle.

[image]

please help me how to prove this,i've no idea.

and if anyone knows some book with shapes like this and with this kind of approach to topology please introduce it.

thank you

Comment: How do you define the Klein bottle? Are you familiar with its [fundamental polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle#Construction)?

Comment: i just know how to reach the klein bottle via gluing the sides of a square.

Comment: What do you get if you only identify the red sides of the square in the page I linked to?

Comment: sorry,what do you mean?

Comment: Consider [this square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle#mediaviewer/File:Klein_Bottle_Folding_1.svg). Glue the red sides (and only those). Compare the result with the diagram in the question.

Comment: Label the two bounding circles with oppositely oriented arrows. Then slice through the annulus along a radius and label the two edges of the slice with arrows in the same direction. Straighten out the sliced annulus to get the square with indicated identifications that should look familiar.

Answer (score 0):

It's homeomorphic to the connected sum of two projective planes (on $\mathbb{R}$), hence it is the Klein bottle (up to iso, as usual).